# Python: how to plot an image with center coordinates?

Tags: python, image

I used [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) to generate a figure using their static [api](https://www.mapbox.com/help/static-api-playground/).

```
urlI = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v9/static/8.54307,47.37299,12.0,0,0/500x400@2x?access_token=ACCESSKEY'
img = plt.imread(urlI)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor= 'white', figsize=(10,10))
ax.imshow(img)
```

[image]
However I would like to show the picture with center cordinate:

```
x:8.4694058
y:47.3719764
```

and size:

```
width: 500
height: 400
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, but could you try to do ax.set_xlim(8.4694058, your_upper bound) and likewise for the y coord? As for the size you can just use figsize=(5,4)

Comment: @LucaGiorgi the problem is that I don't know my upper/lower bound but just the center

Comment: Then you'd just need to pick a lower and upper bound with equal distance to your center coord, no?

Comment: ok, what stops you to modify the URL you use to use the appropriate centre coordinates?